# MySql Very Large File import

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I have a very large MySql Insert Script that is 70GB and has 22,288,088,954 records for inserting.
What is the best (Fastest) way  to import this file?

I already set up this:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

And I use MySql Command Line Client to execute this file, but it is executing almost 5 days and when I try to see how much total records are inserted after 5 days there are only 4,371,106 records inserted.

I use this sql to find total inserted records:

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'mydatabase'
```

MySql is installed on Win 10 Pro PC, with I5 CPU and 32GB RAM, SSD disk

Can anybody help me and suggest a faster way to import this script because if only 4,000,000 records from 22,288,088,954 in 5 days, it will take a very long time to finish.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that the tag [tah:batch-file] is used for a kind of Windows script, not processing multiple files.

Comment: Why would one do that?
Exporting/Importing this much huge data as insert statements is a very bad idea. You should probably export the data in another format. Or, if you can't get the data again, I would suggest you use some additional program on top of it which processes this file and then triggers the SQL batch inserts and commits commands for smaller chunks.

Comment: @user3782239 What does your `insert` statement look like?

Comment: Have you checked out some of the `little` things such as having a unique integer key would require you to use a Long.

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't believe you. 22 billion rows in 70 GBytes is just over 3 characters per row. If you are using one insert, that is the `(`, `)`, and about one more character.

Second, you no doubt have a problem with the transaction log. Are you doing commits after every insert or few inserts? For optimal performance, you should probably be committing after every 1,000 - 100,000, so the log file doesn't get too big.

Third, the best way to insert the data is not via inserts at all. You should be using `load data infile`. In less than five days, you should be able to write a script to convert the `insert` statements into an input data file. Then you can just load that. Better yet, go back to the original data and extract it in a more suitable format.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff , first of all I don't need to lie, because I need help. For files, there are 68 individual files, so instead I execute them individually, I merged all files in one sql file. Third, when I open that large file using EmEditor Pro, I can open that file, and on right side I can see how big is file and how many rows it has... Here is a link with image that shows how big is file and how many records it have, but I cant wait untill it opens whole [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B997WmP5z7yNZEY4QVBqajJRNnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Gordon +1, I like your answer. All I would add is to break up the input into smaller pieces and run the job more times. This provides the ability to survive an error without having to do the whole thing over again.

Comment: @user3782230 . . . I wasn't trying to imply that you were "lying", which would be intentional.  The numbers you present don't add up.  Three characters for data in each row is a bit meager.  You should check the numbers in your question.